# How to remote into AD Users from the server?

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop

Searches aren't coming up with much results. I don't think I'm wording my searches correctly.

Windows Server 2016

I would like to be able to remote into any User in Active Directory. Currently I am having to look into the DHCP Address Leases and plug that User's IP address into Remote Desktop Connection along with the users credentials.

Is there a way as an administrator to be able to simply select a User from the Active Directory Users and Computers on the AD Server and remote into the User's computer through that screen?

Thank you for your help, I am new to active directory.

- Chris

Comment: `Is there a way as an administrator to be able to simply select a User from the Active Directory Users and Computers on the AD Server and remote into the User's computer through that screen?` - No, there isn't.

Comment: Try searching on the phrase `Remote Assistance`. Generally speaking, the user has to send you a request for assistance/remote control.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're remoting into a **computer**, not a user.

Active Directory doesn't display what computer a user is logged onto. If a user has logged onto a domain-joined workstation, opened their email and opened a network file share, they've done literally 4 separate logon activities on 4 different computers (unless you're hosting your file server and email on the domain controller).

You can troll your DC logs to find the most recent logon activity and which machine it originated from (and there are tools that can speed it up... a bit), but if the last logon was via the Exchange server when the user opened their mailbox, it's not that helpful.

System admins implement various shortcuts to find what workstation a user is logged into - we fairly crudely have a workstation logon script that writes the last logged-on workstation into a attribute in the user account, as well as logging the same into a text file on the workstation. Hunting around in DCHP the way you're doing is another method, I suppose.

Once you know which workstation the user is on, then some of the suggested methods like Remote Assistance, the SCCM equivalent or even Teamviewer or Skype desktop sharing will get you into their Windows session. If you're not doing support of the user, you can always RDP to the workstation when they are not logged on. (You can also always RDP to the workstation when they ARE logged on and kick them off so you can fix whatever, but that tends to make people grumpy.)

I highly recommend requiring that anyone needing user support MUST supply the computer name they are working on (and their contact details) when they make the service request (whatever method you use to manage service requests). It's not very efficient wasting your valuable (paid?) time trying to determine information that could have been supplied by a user in a few seconds.

I also highly recommend you get some basic Windows support training. To be honest, knowing the operations you can carry out on a user object vs a computer (in any distributed environment, whether you're using straight LDAP, eDirectory or AD) is pretty fundamental.